# Binary Data folder is not getting updated in DXA 2.2

Tags: dxa, publishing, dxa2.2, multimedia, 9.6

In DXA 2.2, After deleting a .js file from Multimedia and publishing it, the file is not getting removed from the Binary Data folder. Tridion version: 9.6.

Please provide some input.

Comment: I am slightly confused - if you deleted the file, how did you publish it? Normally, Tridion won't let you delete the file if it is already published, so there's probably something more complex happening, do you have more details, were you able to find anything else?

Comment: @JANANI, Welcome to Tridion StackExchange, I assume you are trying to delete the multimedia component used in the page and republish it. but DXA won't delete that file automatically from the Binary Data folder, It is best to schedule a job that removes old files on a regular basis.

Comment: This is a bug in .net version of DXA 2.2 ( not sure about java). This used to work in DXA 1.8.  CleanupLocalFile method is missing in BinaryFileManager.cs (DXA2.2) -https://github.com/RWS/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/release/2.2/Sdl.Web.Tridion/Statics/BinaryFileManager.cs; but was available in BinaryFileManager.cs (DXA 1.8) - https://github.com/RWS/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/release/1.8/Sdl.Web.Tridion/Statics/BinaryFileManager.cs